# Does "nails" imply painted nails?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

A [google image search for "nails"](https://www.google.bg/search?q=nails&tbm=isch) displays almost exclusively painted nails, whereas [searching for "fingernails"](https://www.google.bg/search?q=fingernails&tbm=isch) displays almost exclusively unpainted nails. Is this due to a difference in the meaning and common usage of the two words, or for some other reason?

Comment: Google image searches will tell you things only about the contents of peoples websites.  They should not be used to help define the meaning of words.  Use a **dictionary** for that.

Comment: When people paint their nails, they are unlikely to say _fingernails_ since it seems obvious they didn't paint the naiuls they used to hang a painting. In a medical context, I can imagine a distinction is usually made between finger- and toenails so when you encounter _fingernails_ they are likely in a context of "a certain part of your body" whereas "nails" will get you a lot of hits that have to do with painting them. Basically, I agree with @MaxWilliams.

Comment: A [Google image search for ***eyelashes***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1208&bih=816&q=eyelashes&oq=eyelashes&gs_l=img.3..0l10.2141.4263.0.4673.9.5.0.4.4.0.111.342.4j1.5.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.9.365.Ba5Rg6dbFCo) displays almost exclusively mascaraed or false eyelashes. But so does a search for just ***lashes***. What does this prove?

Comment: A google search for "nails" yields those results because they're something you can buy. Q&A web sites might be 1% of the internet (we all know what the other 90% is). The last 9% is for making money.

Answer (score 4):

It's because when searching "nails," your results include "gel nails," "acrylic nails," "nail polish," "nail art," "fake nails."

Whereas "fingernails," especially as one word, imply natural, bare, undecorated nails.

Comment: And perhaps most importantly "paint my nails", "painted nails" and so on. That is, "painted" tends to lead to saying "nails", not the other way around as the question assumes.